# Jmeter log replay taking more time

Tags: jmeter

Jmeter log replay taking more time .. can we able to use access log sampler in multiple thread? if so how to share the log files to all the threads?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your access log into a CSV file with a script and use [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) in conjunction with the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers - this way you will get it replayed with the multiple threads. See [Stop Making Assumptions! Learn How to Replay Your Production Traffic With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/stop-making-assumptions-learn-how-replay-your-production-traffic-jmeter) article to get the idea in more details and see the example implementation.

---

However be aware that this way most likely you won't be able to replay complex end-to-end scenarios, only simple [HTTP GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) requests which are not authenticated can be replayed this way. For quick-and-dirty test plan it might be enough, however it is much better to come up with modular test plan, reusable components, full control of workload, etc. so I would rather recommend [building a web test plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html) from scratch.